# Find the median from a CSV File using Python

Tags: python, median

I have a CSV file named 'salaries.csv' The content of the files is as follows:

> City,Job,Salary
>   Delhi,Doctors,500
>   Delhi,Lawyers,400
>   Delhi,Plumbers,100
>   London,Doctors,800
>   London,Lawyers,700
>   London,Plumbers,300
>   Tokyo,Doctors,900
>   Tokyo,Lawyers,800
>   Tokyo,Plumbers,400
>   Lawyers,Doctors,300
>   Lawyers,Lawyers,400
>   Lawyers,Plumbers,500
>   Hong Kong,Doctors,1800
>   Hong Kong,Lawyers,1100
>   Hong Kong,Plumbers,1000
>   Moscow,Doctors,300
>   Moscow,Lawyers,200
>   Moscow,Plumbers,100
>   Berlin,Doctors,800
>   Berlin,Plumbers,900
>   Paris,Doctors,900
>   Paris,Lawyers,800
>   Paris,Plumbers,500
>   Paris,Dog catchers,400

I need to print the median salary of each profession. I tried a code, which shows some error.

My code is :

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import sqlite3
import csv
import operator #from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

data = open('sal.csv', 'r').read()
string = ''.join(data)
f = StringIO(string)
reader = csv.reader(f)
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''create table data (City text, Job text, Salary real)''')
conn.commit()
count = 0

for e in reader:
    if count==0:
        print ""
    else:
        e[0]=str(e[0])
        e[1]=str(e[1])
        e[2] = float(e[2])
        c.execute("""insert into data values (?,?,?)""", e)
        count=count+1
        conn.commit()

labels = []
counts = []
count = 0
c.execute('''select count(Salary),Job from data group by Job''')

for row in c:
      for i in row:
            if count==0:
               counts.append(i)
               count=count+1
           else:
                count=0
      labels.append(i)

c.execute('''select Salary,Job from data order by Job''')

count = 1
count1 = 1
temp = 0
pri = 0
lis = []

for row in c:
      lis.append(row)
for cons in counts:
      if cons%2 == 0:
         pri = cons/2
     else:
         pri = (cons+1)/2
     if count1 == 1:
        for li in lis:
              if count == pri:
                  print "Median is ",li
        count = count + 1
        count = 0
        temp = pri+cons
     else:
        for li in lis:
              if count == temp:
                  print "Median is",li
              count = count+1
              count = 0
              temp = temp + pri
       count1 = count1 + 1
```

However, it is showing some error:

```
IndentationError('expected an indented block', ('', 28, 2, 'if count==0:\n'))
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Do you really need *all* of it to demonstrate the problem you are having? Reduce your program to the shortest possible program that demonstrates your error. I suspect the result will be a two- or three-line program.

Comment: @Robᵩ Kindly help me in this regard. A am a newbie in the Python field.

Comment: So you want the average salary for each profession?

Comment: @DanielJimenez Yes

` Plumbers 500
Lawyers 700
Doctors 800

Comment: @DanielJimenez Any easy solution to it?

Comment: if you are using a database, why not use the average function?

Comment: eg.  select avg(salary), job from data group by job;

Comment: FYI: Average and median are not the same thing - they are related but different functions.

Comment: Your indentation of the line in the error message doesn't match the corresponding `else` statement below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  defaultdict to put all the salaries for each profession then just get the median.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("C:/Users/jimenez/Desktop/a.csv","r") as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        d[row[1]].append(float(row[2]))   

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print "{} median is {}".format(k,sorted(v)[len(v) // 2])
    print "{} average is {}".format(k,sum(v)/len(v))
```

Outputs

```
Plumbers median is 500.0
Plumbers average is 475.0
Lawyers median is 700.0
Lawyers average is 628.571428571
Dog catchers median is 400.0
Dog catchers average is 400.0
Doctors median is 800.0
Doctors average is 787.5
```

Comment: You are using Python 2 - so, be careful of the division for the acverage: `.format(k,sum(v)/len(v))` - as it round down to an int, unless you fix it.

Comment: Edited per @jsbueno suggestion

Comment: @DanielJimenez I am using Python 2, the format is showing error!

Comment: @DanielJimenez
~from __future__ import with_statement
import csv

from collections import defaultdict

with open("salaries.csv","r") as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        d[row[1]].append(row[2])    

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print "{%d} median is {%d}" % (k,sorted(v)[len(v) // 2])

Comment: Im using 2.7 and it it works for me. I don't think you are using the format function in your comment. You want  print `"{%s} median is {%d}" % (k,sorted(v)[len(v) // 2]) `

Comment: @DanielJimenez

AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'format'",) Error

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: You need numbered formatting for old versions of python, based on your last question you are using something < 2.5

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you use `pandas` (http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['City', 'Job', 'Salary'])
df.groupby('Job').median()

#               Salary
# Job                 
# Doctors          800
# Dog catchers     400
# Lawyers          700
# Plumbers         450
```

If you want the average instead of the median,

```
df.groupby('Job').mean()

#                   Salary
# Job                     
# Doctors       787.500000
# Dog catchers  400.000000
# Lawyers       628.571429
# Plumbers      475.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is computing he median, and not inserting everything in a SQL databas and scrambling it about,
it is a matter of just reading all lines, group all salaries in a list, and get the median from there - this reduces your hundred-line-magnitude script to:

```
import csv
professions = {}

with open("sal.csv") as data:
    for city, profession, salary in csv.reader(data):
        professions.setdefault(profession.strip(), []).append(int(salary.strip()))

for profession, salaries in sorted(professions.items()):
    print ("{}: {}".format(profession, sorted(salaries)[len(salaries//2)] ))
```

(give or take "1" to get the proper median from the sorted salaries)

Comment: In the comments, the OP said he meant "average."  Also, I doubt that your code runs since dictionaries do not have `set_default` as an attribute. (turnabout.)

Comment: FIxed "set_default" to "setdefault". Thanks for that. Also, this example code does not skip the header line - but the idea to answer the question is just the same

Comment: In addition to removing the header line, there is another change needed to make the code run:  `len(salaries//2)` --> `len(salaries)//2`.