# How to access csv file data in django?

Tags: django, django-file-upload

I want a webpage in django that accepts csv file from the user and need to process         that data.could you please help me

Comment: You should to regard what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Python has builtin library to parsing csv file and process data of csv file according to your logic

Comment: but how can i use it in django

Comment: If you want to save csv file data to model then add model structure in your question. I'll update my answer according to model

Comment: i want a simple webpage with csv file upload and to find the mean of all the data of that file.

Comment: could me please help with the code for the above problem.i will be thankful to you in advance

Comment: Can you give me example of data you have in csv file ?   Check this question can solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634463/find-the-median-from-a-csv-file-using-python?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: The csv file contains just integer data and i want to access that data atleast to find mean of all data .this needs to be done in django .could you please provide me the code